# Springboot 2 actuator how to exclude the tomcat metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

As title, how to exclude tomcat metrics from the actuator endpoints via properties?

There are many management.metrics.binders, but not one for disabling the tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still looking for the answer. You can use the property
**management.metrics.enable.tomcat=false**

Refer spring doc for more details

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_per_meter_properties

Thanks

Comment: Updated link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties